# Run time used by JQuery

Tags: jquery, runtime

Is it correct to assume that JQuery is not actually an implementation of ECMA spec but rather some kind of framework?

If that is true, what run time does it use? For example in IE, does it finally end up with the javascript engine in IE?

thanks

Sesh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery is written entirely in Javascript. It runs using whatever Javascript engine is in the browser that runs it, so if you run it in IE, it uses IE's engine. In Firefox it uses the Firefox engine.

Basically it's just an API built around the semi-standard Javascript API every browser complies to. It takes any quirks between browsers into account and smooths them out (internally) for you so that everything works the same regardless of browser when you develop within the framework.

It follows the ECMA spec only as much as every browser allows.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is a framework written in javascript, and so is of course run by the browsers javascript engine.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is not an ECMA specification implementation, but a javascript framework. It is able to run in all modern browsers and provides an API that makes javascript development easier. Because the javascript runtime is different among the browsers, jQuery detects the browser dynamically and acts accordingly.

So to answer your question, in IE it ends running under IE's javascript engine.